# 404 Not Found page on NGINX server

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

So, I tried to deploy a react app with Docker. It works, when I go to http://localhost:3000/ it shows me the home the login page (as expected). I can also login and goes me to the home page and so on. But if I refresh any page except for http://localhost:3000/ I received 404 Not Found.
The errors in docker logs are something like:

- 30#30: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3000"
- 30#30: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/users" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /users HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3000", referrer: "http://localhost:3000/users"

---

```
nginx.conf file:

   upstream backend{
        server ${BACKEND}:8080       max_fails=3 fail_timeout=240s;
    }

server {

    listen  3000;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {    
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

}
```

---

App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {
  const AdminRoute = ProtectedRoute(Admin, ['ADMIN']);
  const UsersRoute = ProtectedRoute(Users, ['ADMIN']);
  const DevicesRoute = ProtectedRoute(Devices, ['ADMIN']);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/client" element={<Client />} />
        <Route path="/unauthorized" element={<Unauthorized />} />
        <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminRoute />} />
        <Route path="/users" element={<UsersRoute />} />
        <Route path="/devices" element={<DevicesRoute />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 as BUILD_IMAGE

WORKDIR /app/react-app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/react-app/dist .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

---

I tried also this nginx.file:

```
server {

    listen  3000;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {    
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }

}
```

and in this situation, I received: This page isn’t working. Localhost didn’t send any data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: @HansKilian not really